Why does TD3/DDPG use −  [  (  ,  (  ) ) ] −E[Q(s,π(s))] as the policy loss without causing Q-values to go to infinity?
I tried to understand why TD3/DDPG use a policy loss of −E[Q(s,π(s))], which should make the policy maximize Q-values. I expected this to push Q-values to infinity over time, as there’s no explicit constraint

Please, edit your post (both the body and title) to format your formulas with MathJax. Thanks.

For TD3/DDP the Q-value is derived from the expected return based on the future rewards which also depend on the policy and the dynamics of the environment including discount factor for future rewards. As the policy improves, the Q-values for certain actions may increase, but they are also constrained by the environment's MDP dynamics whose Bellman optimality equation's fixed point contraction property ultimately prevents the optimized Q-values from exploding.
In addition, DDPG and TD3 utilize experience replay and a target network approach to stabilize learning which help prevent the policy from diverging too quickly and maintain a balance in learning.

Balance of exploration and exploitation: The core of reinforcement learning lies in the balance of exploration and exploitation, and using a strategy loss function with negative expected Q values in combination with exploration strategies (such as noise strategies) can ensure that the use of existing knowledge does not lead to divergence of Q values while constantly exploring new actions

$Q(s, a)$ is a trained model that should correspond to the true $Q$. Usually, either the action space is bounded, or such $Q$ has some concave-like property (the limits for each $a$ are $\infty$).
This means that you are either trying to maximize a concave function, or you are dealing with some constrained setting (bounded action space)
If you assume you have the exact $Q$, and it's not strongly concave, than that means that the optimal action is an unbounded one
If you don't have the exact $Q$, but you are learning it, you usually do one step of policy gradient (slightly change the policy) and then let the $Q$-function to update sometimes (delayed policy update in TD3) so that it adapts to the new policy

But limiting the actions will not limit the q and Not always the q is concave.

@Omar please specify if you refer to the "ideal" Q or the learnt "Q"... in the first case, if the optimal Q (eht exact one) is not concave, then the optimal action is undefined, and that's ok... if I tell you "your reward is twice what you bet", your optimal bet is infinite...
